# How to change position of collision object in Moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, collision-object

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I used something similar to the following code according to [this tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html) to spawn a collision object in the world:

```
moveit_msgs::CollisionObject collision_object;
collision_object.header.frame_id = group.getPlanningFrame();

/* The id of the object is used to identify it. */
collision_object.id = "box1";

/* Define a box to add to the world. */
shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive primitive;
primitive.type = primitive.BOX;
primitive.dimensions.resize(3);
primitive.dimensions[0] = 0.4;
primitive.dimensions[1] = 0.1;
primitive.dimensions[2] = 0.4;

/* A pose for the box (specified relative to frame_id) */
geometry_msgs::Pose box_pose;
box_pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
box_pose.position.x =  0.6;
box_pose.position.y = -0.4;
box_pose.position.z =  1.2;

collision_object.primitives.push_back(primitive);
collision_object.primitive_poses.push_back(box_pose);
collision_object.operation = collision_object.ADD;

std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_objects;
collision_objects.push_back(collision_object);
```

I have 2 questions now:

1. Is there a way to change the position of the collision object directly?
2. Can the position be changed when the object is attached to a robot?

My first idea would have been to remove the object and add it again in the scene, but that is quite lengthy though. Would be nice if someone can tell me if there is a shorter way to do this :)
Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276194/how-to-change-position-of-collision-object-in-moveit/) by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2017-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

1. It is possible.
2. Not sure. If the object is attached to the robot through the URDF then is not possible. If you attach the object using moveit_msgs/AttachedCollisionObject.h it will move with the robot until you detach it.

Check this code I implemented, it uses the MOVE operation and works fine. I hope it will be helpful.

It listens to three different transformations published by aruco_ros package and then it updates the position of the objects in the planning scene. The robot avoids collision with these objects. The moveit_msgs::CollisionObject bin is reused since the three objects have the same mesh.

Nicolas.

```
#include "geometric_shapes/shapes.h"
#include "geometric_shapes/mesh_operations.h"
#include "geometric_shapes/shape_operations.h"

#include <moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h>
#include <moveit_msgs/CollisionObject.h>

#include <tf/transform_listener.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

ros::init(argc, argv, "bins_tracker");
ros::NodeHandle node; 

tf::TransformListener listener; //tf listener & transformations
tf::StampedTransform t_bin1;
tf::StampedTransform t_bin2;
tf::StampedTransform t_bin3;

std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_objects; //vector of objects
std::vector<std::string> object_ids; //vector of strings (names of objects)
object_ids.push_back("Bin1");
object_ids.push_back("Bin2");
object_ids.push_back("Bin3");
    
moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface; //planning interface
moveit_msgs::CollisionObject bin; //Create an object msg

shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://motoman_sda10f_support/meshes/bin.stl"); //find mesh
shape_msgs::Mesh mesh; //create a mesh msg
shapes::ShapeMsg mesh_msg; //create a shape msg
shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m,mesh_msg); //convert shape into a shape msg
ros::Duration(0.5).sleep();
mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(mesh_msg); // shape msg is assigned to mesh msg

bin.header.frame_id = "torso_base_link"; //"father frame"   
bin.meshes.resize(1); //scale
bin.meshes[0]=mesh; //mesh

bin.mesh_poses.resize(1); //vector resize
bin.mesh_poses[0].position.x = 0; //pose
bin.mesh_poses[0].position.y = 0;
bin.mesh_poses[0].position.z = 0;
bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= 1.0;
bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= 0;
bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= 0;
bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= 0;

bin.operation = bin.ADD; //add object to collitions 

bin.id =object_ids[0]; //rename object 
collision_objects.push_back(bin); //you can insert different objects using a vector of collition objects
bin.id=object_ids[1]; //rename object and reuse bin msg struture
collision_objects.push_back(bin); //add object to vector
bin.id=object_ids[2];//rename object and reuse bin msg struture
collision_objects.push_back(bin); //add object to vector

planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects); //add objects to planning interface
    
bin.meshes.clear(); //Clear mesh required for MOVE operation (Only to avoid a warning)
bin.operation = bin.MOVE; //change operation to MOVE

while (node.ok()){
    //Listen to tfs
    try{
        listener.lookupTransform("torso_base_link", "bin1", ros::Time(0), t_bin1);
    }
    
        catch (tf::TransformException ex){
        ROS_WARN("%s",ex.what());
    }

    try{
        listener.lookupTransform("torso_base_link", "bin2", ros::Time(0), t_bin2);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex){
        ROS_WARN("%s",ex.what());
    }
    
    try{
        listener.lookupTransform("torso_base_link", "bin3", ros::Time(0), t_bin3);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex){
        ROS_WARN("%s",ex.what());
    }
    
    collision_objects.clear(); //clear previous data in the vector
    
    bin.id = object_ids[0]; //bin 1 
    bin.mesh_poses[0].position.x = t_bin1.getOrigin().x(); //set pose
    bin.mesh_poses[0].position.y = t_bin1.getOrigin().y();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].position.z = t_bin1.getOrigin().z();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= t_bin1.getRotation().w();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= t_bin1.getRotation().x();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= t_bin1.getRotation().y();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= t_bin1.getRotation().z();
    
    collision_objects.push_back(bin); // add to vector
    
    bin.id = object_ids[1]; //rename
    bin.mesh_poses[0].position.x = t_bin2.getOrigin().x(); //set pose
    bin.mesh_poses[0].position.y = t_bin2.getOrigin().y();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].position.z = t_bin2.getOrigin().z();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= t_bin2.getRotation().w();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= t_bin2.getRotation().x();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= t_bin2.getRotation().y();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= t_bin2.getRotation().z();
    
    collision_objects.push_back(bin); //add to vector
    
    bin.id = object_ids[2]; //rename
    bin.mesh_poses[0].position.x = t_bin3.getOrigin().x(); //add vector
    bin.mesh_poses[0].position.y = t_bin3.getOrigin().y();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].position.z = t_bin3.getOrigin().z();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= t_bin3.getRotation().w();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= t_bin3.getRotation().x();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= t_bin3.getRotation().y();
    bin.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= t_bin3.getRotation().z();
    
    collision_objects.push_back(bin); //add to vector

    planning_scene_interface.applyCollisionObjects(collision_objects); //apply changes to planning interface
    ros::Duration(0.5).sleep(); //ZzZzZ
}
planning_scene_interface.removeCollisionObjects(object_ids); //delete objects from planning interface*/

ros::shutdown(); //turn off
return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [CTAI-PUJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/37584/ctai-puj/) with karma: 26 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1